# DCG doubling a count

Tags: prolog, dcg, successor-arithmetics

I am playing around with DCGs and I have this code. This displays `x` number of `0`s and `x` numbers of `A`s.

```
y --> test(Count), as(Count).

test(0) --> [].
test(succ(0)) --> [0].
test(succ(succ(Count))) --> [0], test(Count), [0].

as(0)  -->  []. 
as(succ(Count))  -->  [a],as(Count).
```

my question is how do I pass a functor to make the number of `A`s double the number of `0`s. Here's what I tried, but it doesn't work.

```
y --> test(Count), as(add(Count,Count,R)).
```

If i only want to add one, this is what did and it works fine.

```
y --> test(Count), as(succ(Count)).
```

Comment: Two remarks: use rather `s(X)` in place of `succ(X)`. And `set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars)` and `"0"` in place of `[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
y --> test(Count), as(Count), as(Count).
```

or

```
y --> test(Count), {add(Count,Count,DCount)}, as(DCount).
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can double the `succ` for `test`

```
y --> test(Count), as(Count).

test(0) --> [].
test(succ(succ(Count))) --> [0], test(Count).

as(0)  -->  []. 
as(succ(Count))  -->  [a], as(Count).
```